# Flutter UI freezes when clicked IconButton

Tags: android, flutter, dart, freeze

I am new to flutter/dart. I am trying to develop a Music Player application.
Problem is when my application trying to retrieve all mp3 files from downloads folder.

It lists all audio(mp3) files on emulator, but when I installed APK on my device the button is stuck when pressed.

What can I do ?

*[Emulator : Android 13 Tiramisu]

[Device: Android 11 R]*

```flutter
//requesting permission code
requestPermission() async {
    // Web platform don't support permissions methods.
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      bool permissionStatus = await _audioQuery.permissionsStatus();
      if (!permissionStatus) {
        await _audioQuery.permissionsRequest();
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

//Button code
IconButton(
  icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_rounded, size: 30,), 
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Songs()));
},)
```

```flutter
class _SongsState extends State<Songs> {

body: SafeArea(
          minimum: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 5),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child:ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: getSongList()[0].length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(getSongList()[1][index].split('/').last,style:
                          const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21
                          ),),
                          leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => music_player(selectedSong: getSongList()[1],selectedIndex:index)
                            ));
                          },
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.play_circle,size: 30,)),
                        

  // Removed all brackets to reduce code for SO question

  // function to retrieve all mp3's
  List getSongList(){

    Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download/');
    String mp3Path = dir.toString();

    List<FileSystemEntity> _files;
    List<FileSystemEntity> _songs = [];
    List<String> _songpaths = [];
    _files = dir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false);

    for(FileSystemEntity entity in _files) {
      String path = entity.path;
      if(path.endsWith('.mp3')) {
        _songs.add(entity);
        _songpaths.add(path);
      }
    }
    return [_songs,_songpaths];
  }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of App]

Comment: what to do you mean by stuck, does it refuse to go to the `Songs`, or after going to songs it doesn't load songs?

Comment: @BouncyBits the IconButton is highlighted and pressed and UI also freezed I can only close the app.

Comment: @DimuthDeZoysa did you check Scoped Storage permission for android 11 file access

Answer (score 1):

Basic problem is you are trying to get list of audio files in build method in sync.

You need to do it as async task. Something like this would work...

```dart
class Songs extends StatefulWidget {
  const Songs({super.key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SongsState();
}

class _SongsState extends State<Songs> {
  List<FileSystemEntity>? songs;
  List<String>? songpaths;

  StreamSubscription? _fetchSongs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchSongsAsyc();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchSongsAsyc() async {
    Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download/');
    String mp3Path = dir.toString();

    List<FileSystemEntity> files;
    songs = [];
    songpaths = [];
    _fetchSongs = dir.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false).listen(
      (entity) {
        String path = entity.path;
        if (path.endsWith('.mp3')) {
          songs?.add(entity);
          songpaths?.add(path);
        }
      },
      onDone: () {
        _fetchSongs = null;
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _fetchSongs?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 5),
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          if (songs == null) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: songs?.length ?? 0,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            songpaths![index].split('/').last,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                          ),
                          leading: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => music_player(
                                              selectedSong: songpaths,
                                              selectedIndex: index)));
                                }));
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.play_circle,
                                size: 30,
                              )));
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get music list

```
void getFiles() async { //asyn function to get list of files
  List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
  var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
  var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
  files = await fm.filesTree( 
    excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"],
    extensions: ["mp3"] //optional, to filter files, list only mp3 files
  );
  setState(() {}); //update the UI
}
```

Then to show music list

```
files == null? Text("Searching Files"):
       ListView.builder(  //if file/folder list is grabbed, then show here
          itemCount: files?.length ?? 0,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child:ListTile(
                     title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                     leading: Icon(Icons.audiotrack),
                     trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.redAccent,),
                     onTap: (){
                        // you can add Play/push code over here
                     },
                  )
```

Kindly check this [article](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/21/how-to-list-mp3-audio-files-from-storage-and-sd-card-on-flutter-app/)
Also you can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_query) for more features